# Reoccurring Python error that doesn't make much sense

Tags: python, windows, atom-editor

I keep getting this error while working in a script:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Isn't this an error you'd see in terminal? I'm in Atom text editor. On top of that, it was working a few minutes ago (i.e. giving me errors about my actual code) and I've been working on it with no problem all day long.

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Python, and make sure you check the 'Add to Path' option.

You could also try adding Python to the path variable ([Tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)).

Comment: So I thought timgeb was kidding, but restarting did actually solve the problem. I have however created a Python_Home variable for path so hopefully this won't happen again. I just don't understand how my programs run fine all day long, but out of nowhere stop working for seemingly no reason